# How can I make a printf( ) adapt to a result of unknown length?

Tags: c, printf

I´d like the 'confetti' to adapt to larger numbers by changing the posiotion of the 'stars' and 'lines' accordingly.
Currently it looks good with single digit numbers, but how can I have it adapt to lager ones?

For context:

'r' is a random number between 1 and and an 'n' set by the user. 'r' is then guessed by the user. 't' tells the user how many tries it took him/her/div to find it.

```
       printf("You got it!\n\n"); 
       printf("*   *   *\n");     //adapt confetti to r larger than one digit ?
       printf(" \\  |  /\n");
       printf("    %d\n", r);
          printf((t==1) ? "It took you one try" : "It took you %d tries", t);
```

Comment: With `printf("%8d\n", r);` or `int w=8; printf("%*d\n", w, r);` if the total field width is to be 8 (or computed). And so on.

Comment: You're going to have to figure out the logic to do what you want.  A simple solution might be a lookup table based on the number of digits in `d`.

Comment: To compute, you can find out the length of the number by preparing that first: `char rbuff[16]; int rlen = sprintf(rbuff, "%d", r);`

Comment: @WeatherVane: you can also use `int rlen = snprintf(0, 0, "%d", r):` to get the size without having to allocate a buffer that you're not really going to use.